# Set basename on react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-boilerplate

I'm configuring react-boilerplate to start a project on it.

Our dev environment publishes "dev" versions of the app in sub paths, for example: `example.org/test/project-name`

Then, when we publish the project, it stays on `example.org/`

I'd like to use the browser history (HTML5 API) and not the hash history. But this means that I have to set the `basename` of React Router to match the current environment.

Right now, I'm trying to set up a static basename in this way:

```
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(useBasename(createHistory))({
  basename: '/test/project-name',
});
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);
```

But when I run the application, the homepage is still at `/` instead of `/test/project-name/`.

So, the questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How would you make the basename match the current environment?

Comment: I am on the same boat right now, did you manage to get around this?

Comment: Nope, I just gave up.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the [react-router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md):

> Be aware that useRouterHistory already pre-enhances your history factory with the useQueries and useBasename enhancers from history.
>
> ```
> import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
> import { createHistory } from 'history'
>
> const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
>   basename: '/base-path'
> })
> ```

Comment: Read again my question please.

Comment: Sorry this isn't helpful.  I tried to use the useBasename() initially in several different ways as well and got the same behavior you describe, the basename being ignored.  This fix worked for me.  I assume you tried it as well and it didn't work for you.

Comment: In the code I provided in the question I'm already using `basename`, I need a way to set it dynamically based on my question requirements.

Comment: From what I read you've tried to hardcode the basename to '/test/project-name' and that already failed.  Once that's works (hint above) you can replace the hardcoded name with a configuration property variable.

If you want the basename be set magically from wherever it's running then you're out of luck.  But you could scrap the whole basename thing and use <Redirect from="*" to="/" /> to wildcard redirect any url to your single page application.  It works to run your app in one tomcat context without additional configuration.